# Redirect using javascript in a UIWebView in iOS 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios4, uiwebview

I have a webview in an iOS App. I have a select box with some values and some javascript code to be executed when the combo changes.

In the browser the same html works ok, but in webview my window.location = url sentence is not working.

How can I do redirect to an url through javascript?

Thanks

Comment: It did not worked. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = url;
```

**EDIT:**
Try to test your code in mobile Safari on your iOS device (e.g. make the page accessible via your Wi-Fi network) and see what's happening. If it doesn't work as well, you'll probably need to check if your redirection executes at all and if your jQuery code does not stop redirection.

**EDIT2:**
Do you conform to UIWebViewDelegate protocol and implement its `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method? If not, implement it and return YES if the web view should begin handling your request (you can filter request you want to handle etc.) - more about UIWebViewDelegate you'll find in docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Solved! The url had to be an absolute one (not relative)!